# Restore a repaired iPhone 5 from backup

Tags: backup, iphone

I had a ton of problems with my iPhone 5. I backed it up and took it to the Apple Store. I got a loaner while getting it fixed and put the latest iPhone backup on loaner phone. Then I got my iPhone back and went to restore from same backup, butd it's not in my options in iTunes. Where could I find this restore point as it has everything in it? Any help would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a backup of the loaner phone to have it available to restore on your repaired phone.

You already appear to have done so on your phone, but if needed, [steps described by Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203977#itunes) are:

> ### Make a backup using iTunes
>
> 1. Open iTunes and connect your device to your computer.
> 2. Save content that you downloaded from the iTunes Store or App Store by clicking File > Devices > Transfer Purchases. If you're using Windows and you [don't see a File menu](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT202662), press the Alt key.
>
> [image: transfer purchases]
>
> 3. Wait for iTunes to finish transferring your purchases. Then, click File > Devices > Back up. If you're using Windows and you [don't see a File menu](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT202662), press the Alt key.
>
> [image: backup from the menu]
>
> 4. After the process ends, you can see if your backup finished successfully by clicking iTunes Preferences > Devices. You should see the name of your device with the date and time that iTunes created the backup.
>
> [image: backup ready for restoration]
>
> Follow more steps [if you need help making an iTunes backup](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT203271). Learn how to [encrypt your backup](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT203790).

Answer (score 0):

The original-phone backup should definitely still be there, and be available. Perhaps you were sent back a replacement iPhone, running a slightly older version of iOS? If the backup is from a newer version of iOS than the target device, iTunes won't show it as an option.

The best thing to do is to first double-check that the backup is there, by going to the Devices section of the iTunes Preferences window. That will show you all of the backups iTunes recognizes as backups :) Let's make sure the backup you want is still listed there.